# could not format hadoop namenode on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to formant namenode, it shows Error:

```
Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.
```

I tried a lot, but could not solve.

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you've already tried...

Comment: Please include atleast the steps you have tried and Java exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try exporting hadoop classpath and then run the command.